when i make a API request to oubrain endpoint " https://api.outbrain.com/amplify/v0.1/reports/marketers/id/promotedContent" i got error
I use Outbrain API. This is the endpoint I used
"https://api.outbrain.com/amplify/v0.1/reports/marketers/id/promotedContent",
and recently, I got this message error
Message: 'Request contains too many entities, limit the number of campaigns and try again'
In the params, I changed the limit from 500 to 10, and unfortunately, this did not help.
Does someone know how I can deal with that?
Reduce the limit from 500 to 10, but this did not help.
My approach is to get correct data without errors.
